# Razor View Engine Not Searching Area View Locations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, routes, viewengine

I am using the default RazorViewEngine, and Area layout configuration, however when i naviagate to a link which uses a view within the area. I get a error stating the View could not be found and searched in the following locations:

```
 ~/Views/Applications/Details.cshtml
 ~/Views/Applications/Details.vbhtml 
 ~/Views/Shared/Details.cshtml
 ~/Views/Shared/Details.vbhtml
```

What I find odd is that it looks as though the view engine does not attempt to search the areas location. What adjustments do I need to make to have the view engine search for views in its area.

Here is the related code I used to define my area.

**Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RouteRegistrar.RegisterRoutesTo(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

**ApplicationAreaRegistration.cs**

```
private void RegisterRoutesTo(RouteCollection routes)
{
        routes.MapRoute("Application_default", AreaName + "/{action}/{applicationId}",
                        new
                        {
                            controller = "Applications",
                            action = "Index",                                
                            applicationDomainId = UrlParameter.Optional
                        }, new { applicationId = @"\d+" });
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@Html.RouteLink(item.Name, "Application_default", new { applicationId = item.Id, action = "Details" })
```

**Physical Directory Layout**

```
Areas \
      \Application
                  \Controllers
                              -ApplicationsController.cs
                   \Views
                         -Details.cshtml
       -ApplicationAreaRegistration.cs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you certain that `RegisterRoutesTo()` in `ApplicationAreaRegistration.cs` is being invoked?  It seems that the Route to your area has not been registered.

I would suggest moving your MapRoute back into the override of `RegisterArea` in `ApplicationAreaRegistration.cs`.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `MapRoute` seems to be an issue. Try adding an `area` declaration

```
routes.MapRoute("Application_default", 
                 AreaName + "/{action}/{applicationId}",
                 new
                 {
                    area= "Application",
                    controller = "Applications",
                    action = "Index",                                
                   applicationDomainId = UrlParameter.Optional
                 }, 
                 new { applicationId = @"\d+" });
```

Also, just double check the various overloads available for `Html.RouteLink` - you may want to add the area the `RouteValues` collection

```
`new {area="Application", applicationId = item.Id, action = "Details"}`
```

when using `RouteLink` outside an area