# Kendo editor templates is not found when placing inside an area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

We're using Kendo grid with Editor templates. In the examples provided by Kendo they store the templates in the global Shared folder for all Views: ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates.

In our project we use Areas and it is more appropriate and logical to store the templates in a Shared folder of particular Area and Controller. However, the template cannot be found if we store it inside an area.

We tried several variations of the structures:
~/Areas/SomeArea/Views/SomeView/Shared/EditorTemplates/editor.cshtml
~/Areas/SomeArea/Views/SomeView/EditorTemplates/editor.cshtml

And the corresponding path in the grid:
 .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("/Shared/Editortemplate/editor")

or 
 .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("/Editortemplate/editor")

However, instead of our template the default one appears.

Where do we do this wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The name passed to the TemplateName method should be just the name of the template not the whole path, in your case it should be "editor". Rest of the work how this template will be found will be done by the Razor ViewEngine.

I would suggest you to check the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621286/razor-view-engine-not-searching-area-view-locations) question which is pretty similar. I hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It was the first, what we tried.